# CInternetSession close thread handle

Tags: c++, multithreading, wininet, beginthreadex

I try to create simple app, which Write/read files on FTP server.
I create a thread

```
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &foo, NULL, 0,NULL );    
    CloseHandle( hThread );
```

A function foo() creates new internet session like this

```
      CInternetSession session(_T("Session"));
```

But after calling CInternetSession session(_T("Session"))  thread ends

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your thread function to wait on an event or enter a loop to prevent the function ending. When that function exits the thread will die.

For example you could use the the windows event API:

```
void foo(){
  // The Event exitSessionEvent must be declared somewhere where the controlling 
  // thread can access it. This might be a global event for example (in a namespace).
  // You must initialise it using CreateEvent.

  CInternetSession session(_T("Session"));
  // ... do some stuff ....
  WaitForSingleObject(exitSessionEvent, INFINITE);
  session.Close(); //Done so cleanup
}
```

Now the thread function will not exit until the event "exitSessionEvent" is set (by someone else).

You can also use a flag of some kind and have a `while(flag)` loop, but events are clearer ways to express yourself in multithreaded applications I think.

Also the thread that created your thread should not be the one to close it, unless it WAITS for it to end. It does not look like you are waiting for your new thread to finish before closing the handle for the thread.
Again if using events then you could do this:

```
HANDLE hThread;
unsigned threadID;
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &foo, NULL, 0,NULL );  
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);  
CloseHandle( hThread );
```

That will wait for the thread to finish before closing the handle.

Comment: It's working even without using Event API. I only added WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE) after _beginthreadex.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: @alinaish - Great. WaitForSingleObject is part of the "Event API" though :) Seeing as how it helped you I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the answer.